# Flutter: IOS Could not build the precompiled application for the device 2021

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Launching lib/main_dev.dart on Kingman’s iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: FK3FA23S5A
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build failed due to concurrent builds, will retry in 2 seconds.
Xcode build done.                                           134.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:

```
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/kingman/Documents/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.7+12/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPlugin.m:149:20: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                       ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/kingman/Desktop/HLH/projects/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/kingman/Documents/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_code_scanner-0.2.1/ios/Classes/QRView.swift:66:13: warning: 'UIAlertView' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
                UIAlertView(title: "Scanning Unavailable", message: "This app does not have permission to access the camera", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Ok").show()
                ^
    /Users/kingman/Desktop/HLH/projects/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/FIRMessagingPubSub.m:283:12: warning: parameter 'expression' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     *  @param expression The topic expression used to generate a pubsub topic
               ^~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/kingman/Desktop/HLH/projects/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/FIRMessagingPubSub.m:283:12: note: did you mean 'topic'?
     *  @param expression The topic expression used to generate a pubsub topic
               ^~~~~~~~~~
               topic
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/kingman/Desktop/HLH/projects/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/server/async_generic_service.cc:19:10: fatal error: 'grpcpp/generic/async_generic_service.h' file not found
    #include <grpcpp/generic/async_generic_service.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/kingman/Desktop/HLH/projects/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/server/async_generic_service.cc:19:10: note: did not find header 'generic/async_generic_service.h' in framework 'grpcpp' (loaded from '/Users/kingman/Desktop/HLH/projects/build/ios/Debug-dev-iphoneos/gRPC-C++')
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Using build description from disk

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on Kingman’s iPhone.
```

Comment: Do a reboot of your machine, clean the flutter project, and could you also please upload your pod file?

Comment: This answer worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77762966/12661064

Answer (score 0):

Running `flutter clean` usually solves the issue for me. Another method that you can try is to generate a fresh ios build. You can delete the `/ios` folder on your Flutter project and generate a new one using `flutter create --platforms=ios [PROJECT]`