# Failed to build iOS app Could not build the precompiled application for the device. Flutter

Tags: flutter, xcode

I'm running into a problem when doing flutter run and trying to run on my physical iPhone.

It says

```
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: U82S29GYHT
Xcode build failed due to concurrent builds, will retry in 2 seconds.
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           113.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2023-08-08 21:56:45.845 xcodebuild[60532:459242] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEFoundation.IDEResultKitSerializationConverter
    xcodebuild: error: Existing file at -resultBundlePath
    "/var/folders/qc/r59z7mgx0v18zk6397764cz00000gn/T/flutter_tools.JRawz4/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir5qvG7L/temporary_xc
    result_bundle.xcresult"
```

I tried searching the problem up but couldn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go To Settings
   [image: 1. Go To Settings]
2. Go To Locations tab and select Command line tools (re-select even if already selected
   [image: 2. Go To Locations tab and select Command line tools (re-select even if already selected)]

3. Try to run the project again, it should work now.